# Having trouble converting multi-level JSON string into object list. Any suggestions?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Hey all so here is the JSON string I expect back `{\"status\":\"success\",\"locations\":[{\"id\":\"24\",\"name\":\"Test New Location Test\",\"contact_first_name\":\"Test\",\"contact_last_name\":\"Test\",\"contact_email\":\"test@email.com\",\"contact_phone_number\":\"(555) 555-5555\",\"billing_address\":\"Test\",\"billing_city\":\"Test\",\"billing_state\":\"AK\",\"billing_zip\":\"55555\",\"traps\":[]}]}`

I am trying to store all the different parts that make up a location to an object list such as id, name, contact_first_name etc.. I think what is tripping me up is the status in front that is making it a little more difficult for me access the different locations.

I am following this tutorial that seems pretty clear but haven't gotten it to work on my end yet. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XssLaKDRV4Y

The below code is part of my Service class and it works in getting the expected http response (mentioned above) and getting the success message. When I uncomment the few lines of code below my app breaks and doesn't store any objects to a list.

```
public async Task<string> GetLocationData()
        {
            var user_id = Convert.ToString(App.Current.Properties["user_id"]);
            var session = Convert.ToString(App.Current.Properties["session"]);
            var key = "randomkeystring"; 

            var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            body.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user_id", user_id));
            body.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("session", session));
            body.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", key));

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "apiurl/api/something") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body) };
                    var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
                    if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return "false";
                    }
                    //string representation
                    var stringResponseFromServer = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //convert JSON to series of objects
                    //LocationCollection locationCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocationCollection>(stringResponseFromServer);
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(locationCollection.locations.Count);
                    var response = JsonConvert
                        .DeserializeObject<GetLocationDataResponse>(stringResponseFromServer);
                    if (response == null) return "false";

                    jsonString.HttpGetLocationDataString += stringResponseFromServer;

                    return stringResponseFromServer;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return "false";
            }
        }
```

My locations.cs looks like this

```
 public class Locations
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string contact_first_name { get; set; }
        public string contact_last_name { get; set; }
        public string contact_email { get; set; }
        public string contact_phone_number { get; set; }
        public string billing_address { get; set; }
        public string billing_city { get; set; }
        public string billing_state { get; set; }
        public string billing_zip { get; set; }
        public string traps { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have a LocationCollection.cs where i hope to store the different locations so I can loop through them later and do whatever I need to do to them.

```
public class LocationCollection
    {
        public List<Locations> locations { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I call the method on my MainPage after the user logs in

```
insectService.GetLocationData().ContinueWith(async (task) =>
            {
                var getLocationDataResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetLocationDataResponse>(task.Result);

                if (getLocationDataResponse.status == "failure")
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Location Data Failure", "Could not retrieve data", "Try Again");

                    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage(), true);
                }
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(getLocationDataResponse.locations.ToString());

                if (getLocationDataResponse.status == "success")
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Location Data Success", "Successfully Recovered Data", "Back to Main Page");
                }
            }); //TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Right now I am able to get the expect JSON string of `{\"status\":\"success\",\"locations\":[{\"id\":\"24\",\"name\":\"Test New Location Test\",\"contact_first_name\":\"Test\",\"contact_last_name\":\"Test\",\"contact_email\":\"test@email.com\",\"contact_phone_number\":\"(555) 555-5555\",\"billing_address\":\"Test\",\"billing_city\":\"Test\",\"billing_state\":\"AK\",\"billing_zip\":\"55555\",\"traps\":[]}]}` and am able to check if the status is success or failure. However I am having trouble storing the different parts of "locations" into a list. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try deserilizing your api result in to a result model, then from there again de serialize to location model. Example:

My API Model

```
  public class ApiResult
{
    public Int32 Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Inside Data I copy all my return result from API, then Deserialize to exact Model.  Here is the example:

```
 public static List<Models.OrderList> RetrieveOrderList(string host, List<Models.FilterCondition> filter)
    {
        string sResult = HttpHelper.httpPost(host + "api/Order/RetrieveOrderList", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filter));
        Models.ApiResult mResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.ApiResult>(sResult);
        if (mResult.Status == 0)
            throw new Exception(mResult.Message);
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.OrderList>>(mResult.Data);
    }
```

If you see the above My return result(string), I deserialize to API result Model, then again finally deserialize to OrderList Model. Hope this help to sort out your issue.

**Update: API Controller** 
I forgot to mention one more point. On the API Controller Side Your result need to copied to API Model. 
Here is the Example

```
[HttpPost]
    public Models.ApiResult RetrieveOrderList(List<Models.FilterCondition> conditions)
    {
        Models.ApiResult mResult = new Models.ApiResult();
        try
        {
            List<Models.OrderList>mOrderList= BLL.Order.RetrieveOrderList(conditions);
            mResult.Status = 1;
            mResult.Message = "Success";
            mResult.Data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mOrderList);
            return mResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mResult.Status = 0;
            mResult.Message = ex.Message;
            mResult.Data = "";
            return mResult;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My locations model didn't match the JSON response. Once I read what the exception was in my catch statement I saw that 'traps' was supposed to be another list. After I changed traps property to a List and then made another class for 'traps' everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please mark your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!